# MigraDocPrintDocument not printing footers

Tags: .net, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm playing around with MigraDoc to print a report.  For some reason, I can't get footers to print - although they show up just fine in the previewer and on generated PDFs.

Here's my code - I trimmed it down to barebones for testing and still can't get it to work.

```
    Dim doc = New MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document

    Dim sec = doc.AddSection

    Dim f = sec.Footers.Primary
    f.AddParagraph("test")

    'Footer appears just fine on previewer
    Dim ddl As String = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.IO.DdlWriter.WriteToString(doc)
    Me.Preview.Ddl = ddl

    'Here's where I tried to print the doc directly.  No footer printed.
    'Dim d As New MigraDoc.Rendering.Printing.MigraDocPrintDocument()
    'd.Renderer = New MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer(doc)
    'd.Renderer.PrepareDocument()
    'd.Print()

    'Here's where I tried to use the previewer's renderer.  Still no footer printed
    'Dim d As New MigraDoc.Rendering.Printing.MigraDocPrintDocument(Me.Preview.Renderer)
    'd.Print()
```

I have a MigraDoc.Rendering.Forms.DocumentPreview control on the form named Preview.  If you run the form as is, the Preview control will display a blank page with a footer that says "Test".  All well and good, but I can't get that footer to print.  If I try to print directly (the first block of commented code), I just get a blank page.  Same when I try to print it using the previewer's renderer (second block of commented code).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is a problem when you try to print with the WPF build of MigraDoc 1.32: nothing gets printed.

It seems your test document contains the footer only. Maybe add a "Hello, World!" paragraph in the normal body. I presume it's not just the footer that is missing.

Printing with the GDI+ build does work IIRC.

Comment: I'm using the GDI+ build.

This just gets weirder.  I added a line under 'Dim sec = doc.AddSection' to try what you suggested anyway.  Added 'sec.AddParagraph("Test Body")' and now I'm getting an error when the previewer tries to render the document - "End of File Expected".   Error goes away if I either remove the line I added OR remove the two lines under it related to the footer.  I can't have content in the main body of the section AND the section's footer at the same time... weird.

When I try printing, I don't get an error but the result is as I expected - "Test Body" and no footer.

Comment: and FYI, the code in the original post is stripped down version of what I was trying to do - originally my code had a ton of stuff in the body when I noticed the footer wasn't printing.  Cleared stuff out bit by bit to try to isolate the problem before posting the question.

Comment: No such problem when I add a table to test content in the body instead of `sec.AddParagraph("Test Body")`:

        `Dim t = sec.AddTable
        t.AddColumn()
        Dim r = t.AddRow
        r.Cells(0).AddParagraph("test")`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that if I set the distance that the footer should be from the bottom of the page and set it greater to or equal to the bottom margin size it would show up.

My bottom margin was .75 inches.  This code put the footer at the very bottom of the page:
`doc.DefaultPageSetup.FooterDistance = new Unit(.75, UnitType.Inch);`

It's pretty strange.  The digital copy of the PDF always had the footer.  It was only when it was printed that it disappeared.  Opening the digital copy and printing through Adobe Reader always printed the footer too.

I think MigraDoc must have something incompatible with some Post Script / PDF processors.  Either way, this is a simple workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show a preview after print then you can use **WebView2** control and use the report path to the pdf file as this.

```
<DockPanel>
    <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView" Source="file:///D:/MyPdfPath.pdf"/>
</DockPanel>
```

This code open's the PDF reader integrated to edge chromium and load your PDF

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf

Advantages:

- You don´t need to take care of printing
- Some rich features like searching, multi page view are ready to use.
- Is multiplatform
- Works with win 7 +
- You save a lot of time !!!!